# ajax function and async: false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here got a weird situation .....

i got a function that cannot edit.(for some reason and i need to use it instead of create a new 1, or overwrite the script is not allowed...)

```
function update_tpl2(form, divtoupdate, exeAlert) {
if(!$('#'+form).length)
    form = 'myform';
if(!$('#'+divtoupdate).length)
    divtoupdate = 'ajax_update';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#' + form).serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: ShowLoading,
    success: function(resp){
        $('#theLoading').dialog('close');
        $('#loading').html('');         
        $('#' + divtoupdate).html(resp);
    }
});
```

}

and i need to add  async: false into that function when run.
is there any way to set the ajax to async: false, by not changing the function and using it.....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

just call the following function with properties = { async: false }

```
function update_tpl2(form, divtoupdate, exeAlert, properties) {
if(!$('#'+form).length)
    form = 'myform';
if(!$('#'+divtoupdate).length)
    divtoupdate = 'ajax_update';

var defaultProps = {
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $('#' + form).serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: ShowLoading,
    success: function(resp){
        $('#theLoading').dialog('close');
        $('#loading').html('');         
        $('#' + divtoupdate).html(resp);
    }
}

jQuery.extend( true, defaultProps, properties)

$.ajax(defaultProps);
```

Comment: but u change the update_tpl2 function dy. this should't be ^^ but thx for trying

Comment: aye, you change the contents of it, but the logic should stay the same. This way you can change the behavior using the properties input argument. if this truly is impossible, then there may be another way. but its a horrible solution! you could do something like setting `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false}); update_tpl2(.....); jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true})`. which would first set async:false as the default value, and then call your function, and then reset to async:true upon completion. more on this here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup